# function not found using cache factory?

Tags: angularjs

im trying to do a little example to learn on using cachefactory but i get the error that 
"Argument 'CacheSampleController' is not a function"

this is my app

```
var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('myCache', function($cacheFactory) {
        return $cacheFactory('myCache', {capacity:3});
    });
```

this is the hmtl file:

```
<div ng-controller="CacheSampleController" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px">

        key: <input type="text" ng-model="key"/><br/>
        value: <input type="text" ng-model="value"/><br/>
        <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="addToCache(key, value)">Add To Cache</button><br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="keyToRead"/><br/>
        <h3>Value from cache: {{readFromCache(keyToRead)}}</h3>
        <h3>Cache Stats: </h3>{{getCacheStats()}}


    </div>
```

and this is the controller

```
eventsApp.controller('CacheSampleController',
    function CacheSampleController($scope, myCache) {
        $scope.addToCache = function(key, value) {
            myCache.put(key, value);
        };

        $scope.readFromCache = function(key) {
            return myCache.get(key);
        };

        $scope.getCacheStats = function() {
            return myCache.info();
        };
    }
);
```

im not sure if it could be a syntax error or something else that im just not seeing?
thanks

Comment: This all seems be be valid code, maybe provide a plunkr

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/pyue7MnBm8nM9SXYSGyB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Add the ng-app to the htm elemvent

```
<html ng-app="eventsApp">
```

Load your js files in this order

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

And your service should look like this

```
var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', [])
.factory('myCache', function($cacheFactory) {
    return $cacheFactory('myCache', {capacity:3});
});
```

Check this: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iIxdvB4M6rRI3vSMczSm?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You must include (CacheSampleController.js) to your page like this:

```
<script src="/js/controllers/CacheSampleController.js"></script>
```

Add it after (app.js) line and I am sure it will work.